# ListView divider not visible

Tags: android, divider

A ListActivity uses an extension of BaseAdapter and the following layout:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"     
        android:background="@color/application_background_color">

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider"
    android:dividerHeight="2dip" android:clickable="true"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"    
    android:cacheColorHint="@color/application_background_color">
</ListView>

   </LinearLayout>
```

It inflates the following layout for the rows:

```
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/Row" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:textSize="20dip" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_margin="8dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"></TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

The drawable/divider.xml looks like this at the moment, but I've tried all different kinds:

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="line">
      <stroke android:color="#FF000000">
      </stroke>
    </shape>
```

If I read the drawable from an image it works. Why doesn't it work when I define the drawable as a .xml file?

**Update**:
The code is following the same pattern as the EfficientAdapter in the Android Developer examples:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

Comment: maybe the reason is in your Adapter. Just try to return true in your adapter's areAllItemsEnabled() method.

Answer (score 2):

Code below works for me:

list layout:

```
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:textFilterEnabled="false"
    style="@style/ListDivider"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="ListDivider">
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/my_shape</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">5dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

my_shape:

```
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <padding
            android:top="2dp"
            android:left="2dp"
            android:right="2dp"
            android:bottom="2dp" />
        <corners
            android:radius="5dp" />
        <solid
            android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </shape>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work in my code.. This means it's probably something in the code which is causing this issue and not in the xml files.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my workaround for dashed divider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="1dip">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FF123243" />

            <stroke
                android:dashGap="5dp"
                android:dashWidth="8dp"
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#FF000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Just make sure to "sync" second shape's color with list's background and divider heights.